# PHP form entry 0 returning NULL

Tags: php

```
// removed from original post
//        if (!empty($_POST['user_inputA2'])) {

function formA2 () {

   function test_input_A2($data) {
      $data = trim($data);
      $data = stripslashes($data);
      $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
      return $data;
   }

?>

<form id="questionA2" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="user_inputA2" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['user_inputA2'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['user_inputA2']); }?>"/><br>
    <input type="submit" name="user_inputA2Submit" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px"/>
</form>

<?php



if (!empty($_POST['user_inputA2']) && $_POST['user_inputA2'] !=="0") {
$user_inputA2 = test_input_A2($_POST["user_inputA2"]);
// more variables here, per line -- and add them to the ="" above.

return $user_inputA2;
}
```

}

UPDATE -- code below is what ended up working

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    if ($_POST['user_inputA2'] !="") {
     $user_inputA2 = test_input_A2($_POST["user_inputA2"]);
     // more variables here, per line -- and add them to the ="" above.

    return $user_inputA2;

    }
}
```

}

If I enter anything besides 0, my PHP code for !empty executes.  I have tried alternatives of isset, !== NULL, and even an alternative IF statement of (... === "0" || ... === 0) { $user_inputA2 = "0" }.  Still returns null and the page responds as if nothing was entered in the form.

How can I get the rest of the code to execute if the form entry is 0 (de facto isset or !empty) ?

Comment: Where are your `form` tags?

Comment: And what does the function `test_input_A2()` do?

Comment: Don'y use `empty` by itself for forms. You can use `!empty($var) && $var != 0` or something with the same logic.

Comment: Thank you all three -- full function in now-edited post.  I just retried twentylemon's code, with various permutations of 0 or "0" and != or !==.  Still none works.

Comment: The function triggers two things -- if an input exists non-null.  First, an echo statement.  Second, a head command to the successor URL.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
<?php

// No need for this line
// if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")

if(isset($_POST['user_inputA2']) && $_POST['user_inputA2'] !== '') {
    $user_inputA2 = test_input_A2($_POST['user_inputA2']);
    return $user_inputA2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that still doesn't work.  I'm still getting NULL.

Comment: `$_POST` will always contain string values, hence it will never be NULL or a number. But it could be a string "NULL". You could var_dump the parameter and return value of `test_input_A2` to help debug.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix on the receiving side.  The code above does return the string of 0, but for implementation, I was asking if comparisons such as empty, !empty, isset.  I changed those to if comparison either == "" or != "", and then the return value of 0 was treated as that actual value, etc.

Sorry the solution ended up being downstream in code from what I posted.  Thanks again, everyone.